# How to set a condition every 1000 loops?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display a message every thousand loops.

This is what i'm going to have to do if not, however my rows go up to 500k or more...

this is what i have tried and works but is very length code write.

```
if rows_processed = "1000" or "2000" or "3000" 'and so on 
then
 'do something
end if
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: iv wrote it twice because its asking for more chars but i think me question is on point. quite annoying that this site goes on number of chars, its quite simple and doesn't help...

Comment: Learn about the modulus operator.

Comment: Thats not how `Or` works and "1000" is a string, not a number.  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file

Comment: Please don't put bogus content (like doubling your question) just to meet the site minimum. You could easily include more details about your issue Such as more of your code. And also, no need to explain your web-searching efforts - I removed all of that. But... your question: just consider how you might be able to check if your current counter is divisible evenly by 1000... And also, using numbers instead of strings...

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator.

Comment: thanks didn't know about mod. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a For/Next loop, then use the MOD operator to check if the remainder of the currently iterated index and 1000 is 0. If you're using some other type of loop then you'll need to keep a counter variable outside of the loop and increment it inside the loop.

Here is an example:

```
'Iterate through each value
For index As Integer = 0 To upper_bounds
    'Check if the current iteration is a multiple of 1,000
    If index MOD 1000 = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You've reached the next 1k mark.")
    End If
Next
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tWyGEQ)